# Parallel recursive memoization in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, concurrency, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have a memoized divide and conquer algorithm in Scala:

```
val cache = mutable.Map[Int, BigInt]()
cache(1) = BigInt(0)

def dp(n: Int): BigInt = cache.getOrElseUpdate(n, {
  partitions(n).map(i => dp(i)).min
  // partitions is non-recursive function that given an Int returns a list[Int]
})
```

I however want to convert this code to use parallelization while recursing by changing `partitions(n)` to `partitions(n).par` which returns a parallel list instead. But now, I get bad state in my `cache` because that map is not concurrent. When I instantiate `cache` with `SynchronizedMap` trait all my fork joins thread block because all `SynchronizedMap` does is puts a giant `synchronized` block around the `getOrElseUpdate` method call. So what is the Scala idiom for doing a recursive divide and conquer algorithm **in parallel** with memoization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: `val cache = concurrent.TrieMap[Int, BigInt]` - concurrency != synchronization

Answer (score 3):

My rule of thumb: never create your own cache. If you really want to go the mutable route, you might want to look into [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [CacheBuilder class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html). If I recall correctly, it provides proper synchronization (and other goodies) but is still very light-weight.

**Edit:**

Scalaz 7 provides a [`Memo`](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Memo.scala) type that claims to have thread-safe implementations (`immutableHashMapMemo`, `immutableListMapMemo`, `immutableTreeMapMemo`). At first glance, it looks like what you need but I haven't used it myself and I'm a bit sceptical: I think the `var` used to store the respective map should be marked `@volatile` to avoid visibility problems.

Comment: CacheBuilder is the first thing I would have used if I was coding in Java. Being a Scala addict, is there any scala-friendly libraries or idioms to solve this problem? If not, I will accept your answer shortly. Thanks!

Comment: Only thing I know of is the `Memo` type in Scalaz. I edited my answer accordingly.